# SVN throws error when checking out force.com project

Tags: eclipse, svn

I am receiving the following error when I checkout a force.com project using SVN with Eclipse Kepler or Luna:

"An internal error occurred during: Applying updates to newly added force.com projects."

I had previously been able to check out projects in Eclipse.  Now I get this error no matter what project I checkout.

Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Checkout your network connection and SVN plugin in eclipse.. Preferences--> General--> Network

Comment: What should I be looking for?

Comment: Check for proxy if you have any proxy settings.. also try to search in the market place(Help-->Eclipse market place) for any other plugins, this ensure you are able to connect to internet. If both of them are not working please re-install the SVN

Comment: Refreshed from Repo and it is working again.

Answer (score 0):

- Check your network connection and SVN plugin in eclipse
- Preferences--> General--> Network
- Check for proxy if you have any proxy settings
- Try to search in the market place(Help-->Eclipse market place) for
  any other plugins, this ensure you are able to connect to internet.
- Try to re-install the SVN or refresh from Repo